# Install League of Legends on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, games, playonlinux

I tried using the PlayOnLinux but on the install screen the window would stop responding as soon as I clicked next to install.

*Edit
It's a laptop so I understand that it might be more difficult if at all possible. 
Specs - http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?cc=us&lc=en&docname=c03482802

Comment: Post your hardware specs. And in the mean time, follow this guide -> http://www.eurobytes.nl/tutorials/league-of-legends-under-ubuntu

Comment: Do you dual boot Windows? I was unable to run LoL setup successfully, but it worked with an existing install that I copied.

Comment: Maybe useful: http://forums.na.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?t=1946188

Comment: I edited the original post with a link to the specs.

Comment: On how to install lol, follow this: [League of Legends under Ubuntu - EuroBytes](http://www.eurobytes.nl/tutorials/league-of-legends-under-ubuntu) All bug related issues should be asked on the lol Pol page [League Of Legends - Supported software - PlayOnLinux - Run your Windows applications on Linux easily!](http://www.playonlinux.com/en/app-1135-League_Of_Legends.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you duel boot windows and Linux then you should probably install LoL on Windows and then play it on Linux through Wine.

Download the rar version of LoL from [HERE](http://thepiratebay.sx/torrent/8317561/League_Of_Legends_-_Ready_To_Play_-_Version_3.5.13_03_29_13_41) and extract it.

Comment: I tried to dual boot with windows 8 (only version I have at the moment) and it creates an error where Ubuntu cannot boot. Also, like I stated in the original post, I already tried using PlayOnLinux.

Comment: Updated my answer.